# Z'prime R calculation

Tags: r, package

I am looking for an package / function that can automatically calculate the z' prime value, that is commonly used to assess the quality of a drug screening. It uses the values for positive controls (pos) and negative controls (neg), used in the screen.
This can be done manually via the formula:

```
Z_prime <- function(pos, neg) {
  res <- (1 - 3*(sd(pos)+sd(neg))/abs(mean(pos)-mean(neg)))
  return(res)
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you read this article? https://rpubs.com/Kat_T/787828 . It might help. There is also a zprime() function in a somewhat rare package (to me anyway) called imageHTS here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/imageHTS/versions/1.22.0/topics/zprime however it will not install on a modern update of R

Comment: Thank you @JohnGarland ! I will give `zprime()` from the imageHTS package a try.

Comment: @JohnGarland The `zprime()` from the `imageHTS` package worked well, eventually!  I have R version 4.1.3. I had to add `force=T`to install it and it had the `BiocManager` package as a prerequisite, but did the job! Thank you, once more

Comment: Well give me an uptick then on my first comment!  Glad it worked.

Comment: Sure, @JohnGarland, I wanted to do so. Could you please copy paste your reply as an answer and not a comment? I can't upvote comments, there's not ick mark next to them. I even checked online https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387126/green-tick-missing-next-to-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this article? rpubs.com/Kat_T/787828 . It might help. There is also a zprime() function in a somewhat rare package (to me anyway) called imageHTS here: rdocumentation.org/packages/imageHTS/versions/1.22.0/topics/… however it will not install on a modern update of R